# Passing an array to multiple functions in C

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote some code to show scores(numbers) in characters(bar graph) using multiple functions.My code compiles without errors but it seems that my array isn't accessible by my last function.

My last function always shows zero, so not the numbers inside my array.
I wrote the code again and still the same issue.

Can somebody help me solve my issue?

Below is my code, that i tried before

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 5


void ReadCharacter(char);
void ReadArray(int[]);
void ShowScores(int[], char);

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    c = 'a';
    ReadCharacter(c);
    int a[max];
    ReadArray(a);
    ShowScores(a, c);
    getchar();
    return 0;   
}

void ReadCharacter(char c)/*read a character to show in the bar graph*/
{
    printf("geef een karakter in\n");

    scanf_s("%c%*c", &c);    
}

void ReadArray(int a[])/*read an array of scores*/
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<max)
    {
        printf("geef een cijfer in\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void ShowScores(int a[], char c)/*make a bar graph of each score with the given character*/
{
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {

        a[i] = z;
        printf("\n %d heeft een score van: ",a[i]);
        for (int k = 0; k < z; k++)
        {
            printf("%c",c);
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: In the `ReadCharacter` function, the variable `c` is a *local variable* inside the function, it will go out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: `scanf_s("%c%*c", &c);` --> `scanf_s("%c%*c", &c, sizeof(c));`

Comment: And what do you mean by "it seems that my array isn't accessible by my last function"? Can you please elaborate? I also recommend you [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Perhaps you should [learn how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: You're erasing your array's information here: `a[i] = z;`. 
Did you mean to do the reverse? `z = a[i];`.

Comment: the better plan for readcharacter is to have it return the read character

Comment: i'm having an issue with my readcharacter function. I have to give my char a value to use in my readcharacter function. It seems that my scanf isn't updating my character. So a function with return value would be better for this? But it can work in my way too i guess?

Comment: Try to use return value or pass a pointer. E.g `void ReadCharacter(char *c){ ...  scanf_s("%c%*c",  c, sizeof(*c));  }` or `char ReadCharacter(char c){ ...  scanf_s("%c%*c",  &c, sizeof(c));  return c; }` then call `c = ReadCharacter(c);`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning effectively 0 to all array elements in the function `ShowScores`.

The scores you have entered are not printed. You probably wanted to write

```
z = a[i];
```

instead of

```
a[i] = z;
```

Comment: can't believe i made this mistake multiple times... thank you!

Comment: you need to write cobol. there you would say `MOVE A[I] TO Z` (cobol programmers like to shout)